# How to install two modules that depend on each other?

Tags: views

So let's say I have module A and module B.

`A` has a view in which `B` is used and `B` has a view in which `A` is used. The views are exported for installation on module install.
How do you write the dependencies? I can't install either of them cause they are dependent of one another

Comment: This rather seems to be a bad design decision. If you're able to edit the code, you can create a third module responsible for displaying the views in common

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You might want to explain more what is in `A` and `B`, why they are in separate modules, and why you have two views cross-referencing them. Both modules could probably be merged, or one becomes a submodule of the other, not interdependent.

Comment: @IsmailCherri thank you, I've sold the problem this way. I've made a third module for "globally" used views that installs the views after all the modules are installed